# Can someone tell me exactly what this BST code does?

Tags: scala, binary-search-tree

In a recent homework we made the following function to delete the minimum number in a given BST in scala. 
Here is the code for our deleteMin function:

```
def deleteMin(t: SearchTree): (SearchTree, Int) = {
require(t != Empty)
(t: @unchecked) match {
  case Node(Empty, d, r) => (r, d)
  case Node(l, d, r) =>
    val (left, m) = deleteMin(l)
    (Node(left, d, r), m)
  }
}
```

I get most of it but I am still a little hazy as to what the line does:

```
val (left, m) = deleteMin(l)
```

I think it keeps track of the current minimum and keeps the tree that it's traversing intact to use later on.

Then I get even more hazy when we use deleteMin in this function delete:

```
def delete(t: SearchTree, n: Int): SearchTree = {
t match{
  case Empty => Empty
  case Node(l, d, r) =>
    if (n < d) Node(delete(l, n), d, r)/*go left*/
    else if(n > d) Node(l, d, delete(r, n))
    else if(r == Empty) l/*not in the tree at all*/
    else if(l == Empty) r
    else {
      val New = deleteMin(r)
      Node(l, New._2, New._1)
    }
  }
}
```

I don't really know why it's calling deleteMin(r) and everything after that is still a bit confusing

Comment: Are you unsure about the syntax in `val (left, m) = deleteMin(l)`? Are you unsure what `deleteMin` does? Deferring the hazier part.

Comment: I'm mostly confused about what _left_ does in `val (left, m) = deleteMin(l)` @som-snytt

Comment: `deleteMin` returns what's left of the tree you passed in, so `left` is what's left of the left. That should make it left-squared. BTW, I avoid `l` as an ID because it looks like one or eye.